# Embedding YAML alias within YAML string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm trying to declare an alias within my YAML file and use it later on within a string. For example, I declare this:

```
en:
  support_email: &support_email "helpme@foo.com"
  support_text: "Having a problem? Reach out to <a href="*support_email">*support_email</a>"
```

and want `en.support_text` to evaluate to `Having a problem? Reach out to <a href="helpme@foo.com">helpme@foo.com</a>`.

Is there a way to accomplish this? For context, this is within a RoR project.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with YAML itself, because the [specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196) specificity excludes this:

> ### 7.1. Alias Nodes
>
> Subsequent occurrences of a previously [serialized](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#serialize//) node are
>   [presented](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#present//) as *alias nodes*. The first occurrence of the [node](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#node//)
>   must be marked by an [anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor//) to allow subsequent occurrences to be
>   [presented](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#present//) as alias nodes.
>
> An alias node is denoted by the “*” indicator. The alias refers to the
>   most recent preceding [node](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#node//) having the same [anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor//). It is an
>   error for an alias node to use an [anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor//) that does not previously
>   occur in the [document](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#document//). It is not an error to specify an
>   [anchor](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#anchor//) that is not used by any alias node.
>
> **Note that an alias node must not specify any [properties](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#node/property/) or [content](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#content//), as these were already specified at the first occurrence
>   of the [node](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#node//).**
>
> *Example 7.1. Alias Nodes*
>
> ```
> First occurrence: &anchor Foo
> Second occurrence: *anchor
> Override anchor: &anchor Bar
> Reuse anchor: *anchor
> ```

You can however use [variable interpolation with I18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations). Taking your example this would look like:

```yml
en:
  support_email: 'helpme@foo.com'
  support_text: 'Having a problem? Reach out to <a href="mailto:%{support_email}">%{support_email}</a>'
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= t('support_text', support_email: t('support_email')) %>
```

Note that the above is not marked as HTML safe, which can be done by [adding the `_html` suffix changing the last element to `html`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate). Alternatively you can call `.html_safe` on the result yourself or input as raw content using `<%== ... %>` (instead of `<%= ... %>`) or `<%= raw ... %>`.

If you want to assign variables more dynamically consider changing the structure of the YAML file.

```
en:
  support:
    constants:
      message: 'Having a problem?'
      phone: '0123456789'
      email: 'helpme@foo.com'
    help_messages:
      phone:
        text: '%{message} Call us on %{phone}.'
        html: '%{message} Call us on %{phone}.'
      email:
        text: '%{message} Reach out to %{email}.'
        html: '%{message} Reach out to <a href="mailto:%{email}">%{email}</a>.'
```

Now do something like this:

```
<% vars = t('support.constants') %>
<%= t('support.help_messages.email.html', vars) %>
```

You could also move this to your own helper:

```
def t_with_constants(base, path, options = {})
  options = t("#{base}.constants").deep_merge(options)
  t("#{base}.#{path}", options)
end
```

Which allows you to use:

```
<%= t_with_constants('support', 'help_messages.email.html') %>
```

Note that if you're not in the view or helper you might need to use [`I18n.t`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api) instead. Which will doesn't have the quality of life improvements that [`ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#t`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-t) offers (like marking strings as HTML safe).

Of course you can give your own twist to this, but I suggest checking out the [I18n guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and the documentation under [`ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper#translate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate) for additional info.

Comment: Super helpful -- exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!